# Query a database using pandasql filtering based on values from an existing dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pandasql

I would like to query a database using pandasql filtering based on values from an existing dataframe.

For example, I have a dataframe that has user_ids and the date in which they made their most recent purchase. I want information about that user's purchase that occurred on that purchase date. I have a database that I can query to get information from a specific purchase date.
My question is how do I query the database for only the dates I care about from the existing dataframe?

The database is quite large so getting anything other than the specific purchase dates will be too slow.
Below is what I've tried to piece together with my basic understanding. I can get it to work on finding a single date but not for every date at once. I could create a loop and do each date and Purchase_ID one at a time, but I didn't know if there was a way to do all the dates in one query.

```
purchases= dataframe["Purchase_ID"]
payment_dates=dataframe["Purchase_Date"]

info= """
        SELECT Purchase_ID, Purchase_Type, Purchase_Date
        FROM Prucahses_table
        WHERE  Purchase_ID IN purchases [<-This doesn't work like this] AND Purchase_Date = TO_DATE('{}', 'YYYY/MM/DD')""".format(payment_dates)

new_info=pd.read_sql(info, dbconn)
```

Comment: What database are you using? Do you have the ability to create tables?

Comment: an Oracle database. I am not able to create tables. However, I did find out from someone else that there was an existing table that I could get the same user information and date information from that was stored in the dataframe. So I was able to use that table to join it with the Pruchases_table and get the desired result. But I am still curious if there is a way to inject the columns of a dataframe into the sql query

Comment: Unfortunately not. The Oracle engine does not see anything in application layer, here being Python. The best is to dump the data frames into temp tables then run a single `JOIN` query. If data frame is small enough, you would use `IN()` on values or iteratively run SQL query to build a master data frame.